# I want to send verification code SMS by using golang gin-gonic server

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, sms, amazon-sns, verification

In my product, I have to verify the user's phone number. And to do that, I want to send verification code by using SMS
But, I can't find references to send verification code by using golang

- this is my code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/sns"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("creating session")
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("ap-northeast-1"),
    }))
    fmt.Println("session created")

    svc := sns.New(sess)
    fmt.Println("service created")

    params := &sns.PublishInput{
        Message: aws.String("testing 123"),         
        PhoneNumber: aws.String(<"myPhoneNumber">), 
    }
    resp, err := svc.Publish(params)

    if err != nil {
        // Print the error, cast err to awserr.Error to get the Code and
        // Message from an error.
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    // Pretty-print the response data.
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

and i get this response

```
creating session
session created
service created
{
   MessageId: "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX" 
}
```

But Message didn't arrived to me.
Also, i don't know how to check the result by using MessageId in response

Can I get some references for this? or am I need to know about other features first?
Please help me

I just searched many words like "aws SMS using golang", "aws verification code SMS golang"
But It didn't work for me

============================================================

- This is my second try, by using JS! But it also didn't work

```
let { SNSClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-sns");
let { PublishCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-sns");

// Set the AWS Region.
const REGION = "ap-northeast-1"; //e.g. "us-east-1"
// Create SNS service object.
const snsClient = new SNSClient({ region: REGION });

// Set the parameters
const params = {
  Message: "test please" /* required */,
  PhoneNumber: "+821012345678", //PHONE_NUMBER, in the E.164 phone number structure
};

const run = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await snsClient.send(new PublishCommand(params));
    console.log("Success.", data);
    return data; // For unit tests.
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err.stack);
  }
};
run();
```

- And this is JS's response

```
Success. {
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  MessageId: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  SequenceNumber: undefined
}
```

Comment: [you  should create topic first](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/gov2/sns)

Comment: Thanks for your comment☺️
but, I think that topic is feature for subscriber
I just want to send SMS to person who want to sign up to use my application

Answer (score 0):

Please check phone number first. You code seems correct.

AWS SNS SMS follows [E.164](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164#Numbering_formats) format.

> The phone number that receives the message. This must be in E.164 format. For example, a United States phone number might be +12065550101

you can read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html)

From above link:

> When you send an SMS message, specify the phone number using the E.164 format. E.164 is a standard for the phone number structure used for international telecommunication. Phone numbers that follow this format can have a maximum of 15 digits, and they are prefixed with the plus character (+) and the country code. For example, a U.S. phone number in E.164 format would appear as +1XXX5550100.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ☺️
Actually, i check them all,, and i tried to this by using JS
[link](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/sns/src/sns_publishsms.js)

but it didn't work for me ,,,,, 

Comment: I Add my second try by using JS 